# Convert Array[Array[Double]] to Array[Double]

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

How can I convert an array of arrays of doubles to just an array of doubles using Scala 2.10.4?

Convert: `Array[Array[Double]] => Array[Double]`

Comment: @monkjack It is not really the same. In OP's case, ``flatten`` is what he is looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`flatten`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array@flatten[U](implicitasTrav:T=%3ETraversable[U],implicitm:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):Array[U]):

```
val r: Array[Double] = doubleDouble.flatten
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this:

```
val src = Array(Array(1.2,3.4), Array(5.6, 7.8))

val result = for {
a <- src
b <- a
} yield b
```